# Reclaim 100 reputation for associating accounts

Tags: support, reputation, linked-accounts

I remember getting the 100 rep for associating my account in serverfault to other stackexchange sites (stackoverflow was my first account)... then some-how I've lost them.

That only happened in serverfault, I have accounts in other stackexchange sites but I still have those 100 rep points.

Or maybe, I never got the bonus. Anyway ...

**Can I reclaim those 100 reputation points now?**

Answer (score 3):

Visit [serverfault.com/reputation](https://serverfault.com/reputation) perhaps, do you see the -- bonuses (100) listed?  If it is not listed then try clearing your associations on your SF account then re-associating.

Comment: Mine shown "days represented 377". Does that mean it's only counting the days rep changed (as opposed to being on the site)?